# Service data is not updating in Angular Project

Tags: angular, typescript

I've been working on assignment for a while but I could not update the data (Array of Users) in UsersService. I can list if I fill the User[] manually in users.service.ts but If I add new user dynamically, it returns Object Array of User. Im really confused.

My Code:

users.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { User } from "./user";

@Injectable()

export class UsersService {
users: User[] = [];

getUsers(status: string):Array<User> {
    return this.users.filter(p => p.status==status);
}

addNew(user:User) {
    this.users.push(user);
}

setUserStatus(name: string, status: string) {
    var userIndex = this.users.findIndex(p=>p.name==name);
    this.users[userIndex].status = status;
}
}
```

active-users.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UsersService } from '../shared/users.service';
import { User } from '../shared/user';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-active-users',
  templateUrl: './active-users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./active-users.component.css'],
  providers: [UsersService]
})
export class ActiveUsersComponent implements OnInit {

  activeUsers : User[];

  constructor(private _userService: UsersService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activeUsers = this._userService.getUsers('active');
  }

  setStatus(name: string, status: string) {
    this._userService.setUserStatus(name, status);
  }

}
```

inactive-users.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UsersService } from '../shared/users.service';
import { User } from '../shared/user';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-inactive-users',
  templateUrl: './inactive-users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./inactive-users.component.css'],
  providers: [UsersService]
})
export class InactiveUsersComponent implements OnInit {

  inactiveUsers: User[];

  constructor(private _userService: UsersService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.inactiveUsers= this._userService.getUsers('inactive');
  }

  setStatus(name: string, status: string) {
    this._userService.setUserStatus(name, status);
  }

}
```

and there is html files to list service data.
You can also browse my project in github .
https://github.com/bayramorhan/angulardemo/tree/service-assignment/src/app

Template Files

inactive-users.component.html

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Inactive Users</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let user of inactiveUsers"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user text-danger"></i> {{ user.name | uppercase }} <button class="btn btn-xs pull-right btn-primary" (click)="setStatus(user.name,'active')">Set to Active</button></li>
          </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

active-users.component.html

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Active Users</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
      <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let user of activeUsers"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user text-success"></i> {{ user.name | uppercase }} <button class="btn btn-xs pull-right btn-primary" (click)="setStatus(user.name, 'active')">Set to Inactive</button></li>
        </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: it returns Object Array of User but its not updating html content

Comment: are you sure userService user array is populated when you call getUsers in activeUsersComponent?

Comment: @fatemefazli I've got an error when using this pipe > ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
    at invalidPipeArgumentError (common.js:3953)
    at

Comment: @MalinduSandaruwan its okay Im getting empty array when I run my app first time. But even I add new user, It's not updating.

Comment: @OrhanBayram You are not setting the status properly `this.users[userIndex].status == status;`, thats not an assignment operator.

Comment: Okay, another problem was creating new instance for each component. I think that was wrong. Fixed it by removing UsersService provider from each content then added this provider in app.module.ts. but still its not fixed my main problem.

Comment: Should I use .subscribe or something?

Comment: @OrhanBayram Yes, Take advantage of `publish/subscribe` concept in angular which can be achieved using `Subject`.

Comment: I have fixed your code - look at my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked at your GitHub.  There are few issues:

1. You are creating a new instance of service by using `providers: [UsersService]` in all your components - for example - [as seen in `ActiveUsersComponent`](https://github.com/bayramorhan/angulardemo/blob/service-assignment/src/app/active-users/active-users.component.ts#L9). So, user added in instance of `NewUserComponent` will not be visible to other components.  You need to get rid of `providers` arrary from all components and add `UsersService` to providers list in `AppModule`
2. You are calling `getUsers(status)` only in `ngOnInit`.  The way this method is implemented - it is returning a new array from the service's `users` array attribute.  Whenever you add new user, the components will not be notified about new value as change detection of Angular will not kick in for the copy of array stored in components. You may have to change the design such that you return observables from your service.  For now, a dirty fix would be to use `getter` methods - for example - your `InactiveUsersComponent` can be changed to:

   ```
   export class InactiveUsersComponent implements OnInit {
     constructor(private _userService: UsersService) {}

      ngOnInit() {}

      get inactiveUsers() {
        return this._userService.getUsers("inactive");
      }

      setStatus(name: string, status: string) {
        this._userService.setUserStatus(name, status);
      }
   }
   ```

By using getter, we are making call to service always.  Similar change needed in ActiveUsersComponent as well

Answer (score 2):

You are not setting the status properly in `setUserStatus()`

```
setUserStatus(name: string, status: string) {
    var userIndex = this.users.findIndex(p=>p.name==name);
    this.users[userIndex].status = status;  // change this line
}
```

EDIT :

Use `Subject` to emit the newly added users back to the component, because they are not getting reflected inside `this.activeUsers`.

```
export class UsersService {
   users: User[] = [];
   subUser : Subject<User> = new Subject<User>();

   addNew(user: User):Array<User> {
       this.users.push(user);
       this.subUser.next(this.users); // emit users after adding new
   }
}
```

Subscribe to `subUser` in your component

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._userService.subUser.subscribe(
           (users) => {
              this.activeUsers = users;
        })
}
```

Comment: yes, its another issue but my main problem is I cant get updated User array after I add new User.

Comment: Can you add template file to your question in which you are trying to access the users?

Comment: I've added template files.

Comment: My answer is to solve further problems after applying Amit Chigadani's solution. Please have a look

Comment: When do you call `addNew(user)`? And even after calling it, new user will only be added to `this.user` property of your Service. It does not reflect in component's `this.activeUsers` property automatically. You can use `Subject` in your service to immediately notify `this.activeUsers` to update its value.

Answer (score 2):

*My answer is to solve further problems after applying Amit Chigadani's solution.*

The **getUsers** method uses a filter function that will create and return a new array (with filtered data). So after you call that method, adding new users to original **users**
array will not maka any replication in returned array from **getUsers** method.

So you have to again and again call the **getUsers** method when a users is added to original **users** array. If it's not possible you have to return the original **users** array from  **getUsers** method and impement the filtering mechanism in **active-users.component.ts** (may be using a [pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes))

**active-user.component.ts**

```
.... //code

users : User[];

.... //code

ngOnInit() {
  this.users = this._userService.users; // you may use a getter
}
```

.... // code

**active-user.component.html**

```
<li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let user of users | filterPipe: 'active'"><i //Implement the filter pipe
```

Comment: I could not access the html from new-user.component.ts file. And I think its not proper way in Angular. Because the point of using Angular is the advantage of Async support right ? I mean I've created UsersService to prevent calling same methods again and again.

Comment: THink you are not clear about my answer check my new edit. it has some code